# formatting gridview text for one field as well as row dependent on value

Tags: gridview

I have got the following code to alter the colour of the rows in the grid view. This works fine, what i am trying to do is alter the colour of the text for the Date Returned value if it is the same, to the same colour of the row, therefore not being able to see the value.

can anyone help?

```
Protected Sub KitNotReturned(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound

        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

            Dim dateLoaned As String = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "DateLoaned")
            Dim dateReturend As String = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "DateReturned")

            If dateLoaned = dateReturend Then

                e.Row.BackColor = Drawing.Color.HotPink


            End If
        End If

    End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking, if you say this is working fine?

Comment: the code i have to change the colour of the row is working fine, i just want to add something to change the colour of the text of the data item DateReturned.

Comment: I have done this by using 

  e.Row.Cells(4).ForeColor = Drawing.Color.HotPink


thanks

Comment: OK - now I understand!  It's often a good idea to set up an enumeration for gridview columns - eg:

Answer (score 0):

OK - now I understand!  It's often a good idea to set up an enumeration for gridview columns - eg:

```
Enum GvColumn
  Id = 0
  Name = 1
  ...
  DateReturned = 4
End Enum
```

You can then refer to the column as:

```
e.Row.Cells(GvColumn).ForeColor
```

which makes it less likely you'll get an error as you add/delete columns, providing that you keep the enumeration up to date.
Surely the other way you could have done it is to set the text property of the cell to be an empty string:

```
e.Row.Cells(GvColumn).Text=""
```

Finally, you could have set the column up to be a template column, then used FindControl to find the textbox within it.  The template column would look like this:

```
<asp:TemplateColumn Header="Something here">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:textbox id="txtDateReturned" runat="server" text=='<%# Bind("DateReturnedText") %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```

You could then get at this with:

```
Dim tb as TextBox = CType(e.Row.FindControl("txtDateReturned"),TextBox)
```

Just some thoughts!